# FailedDependency Unable to enable intelligence pack in Log Analytics workspace

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-log-analytics, azure-defender

I have an Azure IoT Hub and I have enabled the defender.  I am trying to go to Defender settings and clicking on collection to enable the log analytics storage of the data from the defender and I choose the settings shown below and click save and after a few moments I see the error:

```
FailedDependency
Unable to enable intelligence pack in Log Analytics workspace '/subscriptions/60660099-64fd-4ca3-a1eb-c9c7f4e6e5f4/resourcegroups/main/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/loganalyticsws'. Please provide below info when asking for support: correlationId = 034d605f-aaf8-4817-91ba-6e57d816a014
```

I attempted this on a "Free" IoT hub in another tenant and observed the same error.  I have tried over two days so don't think it is related to an intermittent issue.
 
This is a screenshot of the page and the error.  My Azure IoT Hub is "Standard" billing level for this tenant showing the error here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To enable Data collection settings in Microsoft Defender for IOT. You need to follow certain pre-requisite according to this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-iot/device-builders/quickstart-onboard-iot-hub). **Your** **IOT Hub resource should be created in a Standard Tier.** **It won't work with Free or Basic Tier**.

**I created one IOT Hub resource in Standard Tier like below:-**

[image]

**Enabled Defender for IoT:-**

[image]

***After Deployment > Went to Defender for IoT > Settings > Data Collection > Enable Microsoft Defender for IoT > Choose the Log Analytics workspace you wish to connect to***

[image]

Make sure you have created Log Analytics Workspace and ***Select your subscription and the existing Log analytics workspace or Create a New workspace > Come back to this page > Refresh > and select the Log Analytics Workspace.***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might have missed my mention that the screenshot is actually of a standard tier IoT hub where I first observed this issue.  I then tried it over in another tenant which is where the "free" one is.  For good measure, I just went and repeated the steps you documented here to create a test IoT hub and still see the "FailedDependency Unable to enable intelligence pack in Log Analytics workspace" error when I go to turn save the data collection settings.  Very odd.

Comment: Can you try this in Incognito window chrome or Private window on Edge? As sometimes, There's a cache issue on the Portal that avoids certain operations? Make sure you clear your cache too?

Comment: I just tried as instructed with edge in -private window and cleared cache for all time, everything except saved passwords, and the result is the same failed dependency error.  Very strange it works for you.  I wish it would elaborate on the dependency it thinks is missing.

Comment: Create an Azure support request and share your co-relation Id, This might be needed to be fixed by back end -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request This error is specific to Log Analytics workspace, Did you try creating a new LA workspace and then tried linking it? Also, Hope the LA is from the same subscription as your IOT Hub

Comment: Wants to charge me $29 to create a support request so I'll pass on that.  I did try with a new log analytics workspace and same result.  The LA is in same subscription and resource group as the IoT hub.

Comment: Did you try to enable Intelligent Pack in Log Analytics Workspace >  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/log-analytics/workspace/pack?view=azure-cli-latest#az-monitor-log-analytics-workspace-pack-enable() via rest api- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/intelligence-packs/enable?tabs=HTTP

Comment: I can do that, but what is the intelligence pack to try to enable?  I used the azure cloud shell command "az monitor log-analytics workspace pack list --resource-group main --workspace-name loganalyticsws" to view the packs available to enable and didn't see any iot defender pack.